# How to do an upsert or check results of a sub query before inserting using graphql

Tags: graphql

I need to do what is essentially an upsert.  What's the efficient way of checking for an existing user and doing one mutation vs another.  In my case I need to do a signin if the user exists, otherwise I should call create before signing in.  I am using the graph.cool graphql service.  I can do it as 2 seperate calls, but can is there a way I can write it in graphql so that it's done in one call and wouldn't require a 2nd roundtrip?  Note that I don't have control of the backend and can only use the functions that exist.

https://docs.graph.cool/reference/simple-api/user-authentication

```
mutation {

  // Only create a user if they do not exist already
  // is there a way to do a conditional statement in graphql here?
  createUser(authProvider: { auth0: { idToken: "<idToken>" }}) {
    id
  }

  // always try signing the user in with the token we already got from auth0
  signinUser(input: { auth0: { idToken: "<idToken>" }}) {
    id
    token
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question boils down to "how can I return either a token or an id depending on what the back end decided to do?"

The answer is: [a union type](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types).

```
union authResult = id | token

mutation {
  authenticateUser(authProvider: { auth0: { idToken: "<idToken>" }}) {
    authResult
  }
}
```

Now you have delated the decision of "signin or create?" to the back end, and you get to do it in one trip and find out the result.

Note that because you want to do it in one trip, you must provide all the necessary information in one go - IE you have to provide enough info for the createUser step even if the back end doesn't do the create because the user already exists.

Comment: since the backend is not controlled by me, I can't create another function on it, so will have to use signinUser, createUser, and allUsers - but I can't create an authenticateuser method.  In either secenario I want a token... I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: As far as I know, the only possible answers to your question involve back end changs.   The back-end controls what mutations are available.  If it doesn't provide an upsert mutation to do the job you need, then you have to make two calls to it in order to do the job you want with the functions it provides.'